# Java auto length printing on Brother QL580n label printer (Windows only)

Tags: java, windows, printing

I am desperately trying to print a random length label on my Brother QL580n from Java on Windows.

I've found a way to do it with CUPS but it is not working when executing it from Windows with a Windows printer.

Here is a sample of code using Apache PDFBox:

```
 PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

  PrintService service = null;
  for (PrintService printer : printServices) {
      if (printer.getName().equals("Brother QL-580N")) {
        service = printer;
      }
  }
  PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\label.pdf"));

  Paper paperP = new Paper();

  double width = document.getPage(0).getMediaBox().getWidth();
  double height = document.getPage(0).getMediaBox().getHeight();
  paperP.setSize(width, height);
  paperP.setImageableArea(0, 0, paperP.getWidth(), paperP.getHeight()); // no margins

  // custom page format
  PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
  pageFormat.setPaper(paperP);
  PrinterJob jobP = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
  jobP.setPrintService(service);

  Book book = new Book();
  book.append(new PDFPrintable(document), pageFormat, document.getNumberOfPages());

  jobP.setPageable(book);

  jobP.print();
```

The real length of my pdf label is 40mm but only 29mm are printed which is one the windows default label lengths (even if I change the windows printer preferences to something else than 62 mm x 29 mm)

By the way, I am not able to do it with Adobe Reader too, but I am able to print a custom length label with P-Touch Editor from Brother

EDIT

I've just tried to look at `jobP.getPageFormat( new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet()).getWidth()` and `jobP.getPageFormat( new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet()).getHeight()` and I am getting 62mm and 29 mm so it seems my try to pass a custom PageFormat is not working

Comment: I suspect that this is the problem mentioned in http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3117 . There is a workaround but it requires downloading the source code of PDFPageable copy it and change it, see last comment in link. If it works, please make a comment in the issue.

Comment: I took a look at this issue but I don't see the point with my issue. It seems to be a left margin issue but my issue is more to be able to make auto length work. Could you give me more explanation?
By the way thank you for your comment

Comment: Sorry... another idea, although I suspect it won't help either... does the PDF have the correct size? When you look at the properties tab, is the height long enough?

Comment: Yes I checked the original file with Adobe Reader and with Java and everything's fine
thank you for this suggest too